# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name., but chain EXISTS

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I have created a new chain with the following command

```
iptables -N INPUT2
```

I then attempted to add a fire wall rule with the following command

```
iptables -I INPUT2 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But I get this error

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

However when I attempt to see if the chain exists, it does

```
iptables -L INPUT2

Chain INPUT2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Maybe try `iptables-save` before doing the insert. To be honest, I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: The chain exists, and the target exists. So it must be the match that does not exist. What sort of system is this? What hardware, what kernel version, all of the basic info?

Comment: Assuming you have `/proc/config.gz` what does `zgrep CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK= /proc/config.gz` show?